# How to return a value depending on whether an Optional value is present or not?

Tags: java

I use Optional in a controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/address/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Addresses> getAddressById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

    Optional<Address> address = addressService.getAddressById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity(address.get(), address.isPresent() ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Actually, if there is no value, i get

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

not sure if it's a good way to manage thing.

is there any good pratice

Comment: Yes: Don't use `.get()` without either first checking `.ifPresent()`, or without using `.else()`. What value would you like to put in your response entity in the case of `address` being an empty `Optional`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why would you consider it a good way? You obviously want to return a 404. This doesn't do that.

Comment: Just branch and have two return statements. But first figure out what you want the body to be if there is no address.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
return address.isPresent()
    ? new ResponseEntity(address.get(), HttpStatus.OK)
    : new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

With your current code, you are calling `address.get()` regardless of whether or not a value is present.

Note that for a more informative `NOT_FOUND` response (response code 404), you probably should still include a body in the response (which my suggested code does not do). From the [HTTP spec (RFC 7231) section on 4xx response codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5):

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

According to [RFC 2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119), the key word "SHOULD" means:

> that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the fluent quality of Optionals. Think of them like a Stream:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/address/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<Address> getAddressById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    return addressService.getAddressById(id)
        .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
        .orElse(new ResponseEntity<Address>(NOT_FOUND));
  }
```